# Diamond Problem| Parmeterized constructor is not called of grandparent class

Tags: c++, virtual, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Can someone please explain the multiple inheritance of below ,why parameterize constructor  of d class is not called even though vehicle class is being constructed using parameterize constructor.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class d{
    public:
    d()
    {
        cout<<"in default constructor of d"<<endl;
    }
    d(int x)
    {
        cout<<"in parametrized constructor of d"<<endl;
    }
    void a()
    {
        cout<<"a function of d";
    }
};
class Vehical:virtual public d
{
    public:
    Vehical(int x):d(x)
    {
     cout<<"In paramterized constructor of Vehical"  <<endl;
    }
    void a()
    {
        cout <<"a function of Vehical class"<<endl;
    }
    Vehical()
    {
     cout<<"default constructor of Vehical"<<endl;   
    }
};
class now: virtual  public d
{
public:
void a()
{
    cout <<"a function of now "<<endl;
}
    now()
{
  cout<<"Default constructor of now" <<endl; 
}
};
class car :public  Vehical, public now
{
    public:
    car();
    car(int y):Vehical(y)
    {

    };
     //using d::a;
       using Vehical::a;

};
int main()
{
 car ob(1);
  ob.a();
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
in default constructor of d
In paramterized constructor of Vehical
Default constructor of now
```

Expectation :It should have called paremterized constructor of D instead of default ,as we were constructing vehicle by passing parameter ,which indeed calls the paramterized constructor of D class.

Also if we remove virtual of one class,again we have the diamond problem ? why so?

Scenario 1):
If we remove virtual from vehicle class,we have the below output

```
in default constructor of d
in parametrized constructor of d
In paramterized constructor of Vehical
Default constructor of now
a function of Vehical class
```

Also in above output why default constructor is called first and then parametrize of d class?Also in output why both the constructor of d is called first and then vehicle and now class constructor.

Expectation : It should have called first paramterized constructor of d then parametrize constructor of vehicle then default constructor of d then default constructor of now

Scenario 2)
And now we remove the virtual from now class now and we have the output ,in which default constructor of d is called instead of paramterize ?

```
in default constructor of d
In paramterized constructor of Vehical
in default constructor of d
Default constructor of now
a function of Vehical class
```

Expectation :It should have called paramterized Constructor of D instead of Default one for the first line.

Comment: what output did you expect and why?

Comment: For 1) it should have called paremterized constructor of D instead of default ,as we were constructing vehicle by passing parameter ,which indeed calls the paramterized constructor of D class.

Comment: For 2)It should have called first paramterized construcor of d then parametriozed constructor of vehical then default constructor of d then default constructor of now

Comment: for 3) again it should have called parametrized  constructor instead of default constructor of d

Comment: please include that in the question. And I personally find the last part of the question rather confusing. You are basically asking different questions at once. I would maybe remove everything after "why so?"

Comment: @user463035818 made a few edits :)

Comment: Virtual bases are initialised before ALL non-virtual bases, when constructing the most derived class (the one being instantiated). Non-virtual bases are distinct, and therefore initialised by the class that actually inherits them. The reason for the difference with virtual bases is to resolve ambiguity -  if initialisation of a virtual base differs on different inheritance paths, there is no way to decide which initialisation should be chosen. The standard could , notionally, have specified a set of rules and conditions to decide, but that would be complicated and confusing for programmers.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dreaded Diamond of Death there are two problems:

1.Ambigiuity of the base class - which base class's base class is meant to be chosen when referencing this "grandfather" class.

2.Which constructor of grandfather class use when explicitly calling base classes constructors. Imagine following example:

```
class foo{
    public:
    foo() { }
    foo(int x) {  }
};
class bar : virtual public foo
{
    public:
    using foo::foo;
};
class baz: virtual  public foo
{
public:
    using foo::foo;
};
class clazz :public  bar, public baz
{
public:
    clazz(int i) : bar(i), baz(i+1){}
};
```

Which constructor of `foo` is compiler supposed to choose as only one grandfather is to be created? Well, any choice would mean resolving the contest between conflicting `foo` constructor calls (by conflicting I mean with different arguments). The language design choice in C++ is - do not try to resolve contest, just put the responsability for initializing of grandfather class on programmers back. It makes sense because diamond inheritance is a corner case for which special way of initializing may be required.

You have to call the `d` constructor explicitly in grandchild class constructor:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class d{
    public:
    d()
    {
        cout<<"in default constructor of d"<<endl;
    }
    d(int x)
    {
        cout<<"in parametrized constructor of d"<<endl;
    }
    void a()
    {
        cout<<"a function of d";
    }
};
class Vehical:virtual public d
{
    public:
    Vehical(int x):d(x)
    {
     cout<<"In paramterized constructor of Vehical"  <<endl;
    }
    void a()
    {
        cout <<"a function of Vehical class"<<endl;
    }
    Vehical()
    {
     cout<<"default constructor of Vehical"<<endl;   
    }
};
class now: virtual  public d
{
public:
void a()
{
    cout <<"a function of now "<<endl;
}
    now()
{
  cout<<"Default constructor of now" <<endl; 
}
};
class car :public  Vehical, public now
{
    public:
    car();
    car(int y):Vehical(y), d(y)
    {

    };
     //using d::a;
       using Vehical::a;

};
int main()
{
 car ob(1);
  ob.a();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I know the solution ,but why is this happening? Also i have asked a few more question, it will be helpful if you answer those as well.

Comment: @curositykiller one question per question please

Comment: @user463035818 They all are related ,that's why :)

Comment: @curositykiller Hope it now explains something